# How to write a trigger to prevent booking date overlaps

Tags: sql, triggers

I have a simple booking table:

```
id
date_start (date)
date_end (date)
```

What's the right way to write a trigger that will disallow insertion of bookings that overlap with another booking?

Basically, I can't have 2 bookings that overlap with each other.

Is there a generalised approach to solving this problem?

Comment: what database server are we talking about? (be specific, at least brand and version but maybe also OS and such)

Comment: Any, really. I'm just interested in an abstract approach.

Comment: Should this logic not live in your application?

Comment: If your using Oracle you can use an before insert trigger. But this should going into the business logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a trigger `ON INSERT OR UPDATE` that throws an exception when the following condition is true:

```
EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM bookings
    WHERE date_start <= NEW.date_end
    AND date_end >= NEW.date_start
    AND (INSERTING OR id <> NEW.id)
)
```

The `date_start <= NEW.date_end AND date_end >= NEW.date_start` condition will match any existing overlaps with the new record. The `INSERTING OR id <> NEW.id` condition will exclude the current record in the case of an UPDATE (otherwise it will always overlap with itself).

Note that you can remove the last condition and use two separate triggers if you wish - one for INSERT and one for UPDATE.

You may need to change the exact query depending on your RDBMS but the logic should be the same. Note that in general throwing an exception from a trigger will cause the transaction to be rolled back and the new booking to not be allowed.